# Error 404 after deploying a simple Spring MVC app (without web.xml)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I want to learn some basics of Spring MVC based fully on annotations. I started with [this tutorial](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/your-next-java-web-app-less-xml-no-long-restarts-fewer-hassles-part-1/).

After cloning the repository

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/arnelism/snoutbook
```

and building the `war` file

```
mvn package
```

I am deploying the app by simply copying the `war` file to the `webapps` directory of my Apache Tomcat 7.0.12 instance. I am stopping and starting the server.

```
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMATION: Deploying web application archive Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deploying web application directory docs
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deploying web application directory examples
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deploying web application directory host-manager
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deploying web application directory manager
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMATION: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 12, 2014 3:37:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMATION: Server startup in 8826 ms
```

Unfortunately after this operation I am receiving the error 404 by displaying the page.

```
http://localhost:8080/Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/
```

I have been looking for a solution for over 2 hours and have not been able to find the cause. Did somebody have a similar issue?

### EDIT

I tried with the newest Tomcat version `apache-tomcat-8.0.12`. The problem persists. There is however more info printed in the console while deploying the web app.

```
12-Sep-2014 17:13:20.038 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive D:\Users\b21090094\apac
he-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
12-Sep-2014 17:13:23.132 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.S
essionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for s
ession ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [255] milliseconds.
12-Sep-2014 17:13:23.169 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initializa
tion started
12-Sep-2014 17:13:23.182 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.contex
t.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationCon
text for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Sep 12 17:13:23 CEST
2014]; root of context hierarchy
12-Sep-2014 17:13:23.278 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.contex
t.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.registerDefaultFilters
JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scannin
g
12-Sep-2014 17:13:23.281 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.co
ntext.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions Register
ing annotated classes: [class com.zeroturnaround.snoutbook.init.WebappConfigJpa]

12-Sep-2014 17:13:23.429 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.contex
t.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.registerDefaultFilters
JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scannin
g
12-Sep-2014 17:13:23.921 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.
factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons Pre-instanti
ating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBea
nFactory@7169a1: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internal
ConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internal
AutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequ
iredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnn
otationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnot
ationProcessor,webappConfigJpa,org.springframework.context.annotation.Configurat
ionClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,addPetForm,snoutContoller,s
noutDao,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,delegatingWebMvc
Configuration,requestMappingHandlerMapping,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanName
HandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappin
gHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simp
leControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,proxyTransactionManagementCo
nfiguration,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,tr
ansactionAttributeSource,transactionInterceptor,transactionManager,entityManager
Factory,setupViewResolver,getDataSource]; root of factory hierarchy
12-Sep-2014 17:13:24.225 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.orm.jp
a.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory Buildi
ng JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
12-Sep-2014 17:13:24.657 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.annotations.
common.Version. HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}

12-Sep-2014 17:13:24.676 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version.logV
ersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.2}
12-Sep-2014 17:13:24.681 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environm
ent. HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
12-Sep-2014 17:13:24.686 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environm
ent.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
12-Sep-2014 17:13:24.772 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Conf
iguration.configure HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
12-Sep-2014 17:13:25.524 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.service.jdbc
.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionP
rovider HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb
.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
12-Sep-2014 17:13:26.275 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dial
ect. HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
12-Sep-2014 17:13:26.356 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.trans
action.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator.initiateService HHH000268: Transacti
on strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFacto
ry
12-Sep-2014 17:13:26.374 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.hql.internal
.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory. HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

12-Sep-2014 17:13:26.498 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] . HV0000
01: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
12-Sep-2014 17:13:27.699 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[/addP
et],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto
public java.lang.String com.zeroturnaround.snoutbook.controllers.AddPetForm.setu
pForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)
12-Sep-2014 17:13:27.700 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[/addP
et],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto
 public java.lang.String com.zeroturnaround.snoutbook.controllers.AddPetForm.han
dleSubmit(com.zeroturnaround.snoutbook.form.PetForm,org.springframework.validati
on.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus)
12-Sep-2014 17:13:27.701 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[/pet/
{petId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" ont
o public java.lang.String com.zeroturnaround.snoutbook.controllers.SnoutContolle
r.pet(java.lang.Long,org.springframework.ui.Model)
12-Sep-2014 17:13:27.702 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[/owne
rs],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto pub
lic java.lang.String com.zeroturnaround.snoutbook.controllers.SnoutContoller.lis
tOwners(org.springframework.ui.Model)
12-Sep-2014 17:13:27.762 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/**] on
to handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServle
tHttpRequestHandler]
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.129 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initializa
tion completed in 4960 ms
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.140 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive D:\Users\b21090094\
apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war has finished in 8,103
ms
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.141 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Users\b21090
094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\docs
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.167 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Users\b2
1090094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\docs has finished in 26 ms
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.168 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Users\b21090
094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\examples
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.537 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Users\b2
1090094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\examples has finished in 370 ms
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.538 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Users\b21090
094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\host-manager
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.572 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Users\b2
1090094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\host-manager has finished in 34 ms
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.573 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Users\b21090
094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\manager
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.633 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Users\b2
1090094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\manager has finished in 61 ms
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.633 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory D:\Users\b21090
094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\ROOT
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.659 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Users\b2
1090094\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\webapps\ROOT has finished in 26 ms
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.663 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.676 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12-Sep-2014 17:13:28.682 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start
Server startup in 8701 ms
```

After that I am still getting Error 404.

Comment: What is the type and version of the servlet container you are deploying to?

Comment: I am using `apache-tomcat-7.0.12`.

Comment: Use a newer version of tomcat, there are issues with older 7.0.x versions not being able to correctly detect initializer classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried with `apache-tomcat-8.0.12` and unfortunately the problem persist. There is however more information while deploying the app. I updated the question.

Comment: Did you check if there is any context path for the web app other than `Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Your log did not mention any failure while deploying the app, so looks like you are hitting the wrong url. Check web app context path to get the url right.

Comment: @UreshKuruhuri And how do I check that? In the Manager App the app is defined as Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. How do I check this web app context path?

Comment: I just read the tutorial, and it show a page with an URL of `http://localhost:8080/helloWeb/owners`. Did you try to use `helloWeb` instead of `Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes I did. I tried both `localhost:8080/helloWeb/owners` and `localhost:8080/helloWeb`. The result is the same: Error 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `http://localhost:8080/Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/owners`

When you upload war file to webapp folder of tomcat, by default tomcat let you access the webapp with the war's name. And then when you look at the [web app initializer](https://bitbucket.org/arnelism/snoutbook/src/39469926b5170d6fac72fa707bd1cf92477c6478/src/main/java/com/zeroturnaround/snoutbook/init/Initializer.java?at=default) (the subtitute of `web.xml`), it's registering the `DispatcherServlet` with `/` mapping. Next, you look at the [controller](https://bitbucket.org/arnelism/snoutbook/src/39469926b5170d6fac72fa707bd1cf92477c6478/src/main/java/com/zeroturnaround/snoutbook/controllers/SnoutContoller.java?at=default), it have `@RequestMapping` pointed to `/owners`.
Hence, the path is:

`host:port` + `war-name` + `servlet-mapping` + `controller-mapping`

equals to

`localhost:8080/` + `Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/` + `/` + `owners`

equals to

`http://localhost:8080/Snoutbook-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/owners`

Comment: This is the solution to my problem indeed. Thanks!